# python how to use eulers method with multiple equations

Tags: python, differential-equations

I was given two equations one for the growth healthy people in the population,

```
dh/dt=-.05*h*s+.0003*h,
```

and the other equation is for the infection rate of sick people

```
ds/dt=.05*h*s-.01*s.
```

assume that after 10 days of being infected the people die.

for initial variables h=9000 and s=100

using the differential equations generate a figure predicting the impact of the out come of the infection on the population. It was suggested that eulers method be used, how would I use Eulers method using multiple differential equations? or is there a better method you would suggest and how would you use it?

Comment: What unit does `t` have? The -0.01 in the second equation tells us that after 72 time units half of the sick have died, if no new infections occur. Do you have to incorporate the 10 days somewhere in the computation or is that a comment on the 0.01 coefficient?

Comment: the 10 days is a comment and as for the time it would be in days

Comment: This does not make sense, as without new infection,  the solution for the sick is `s(t)=s(0)*exp(-0.01*t)` and `s(10)=s(0)*exp(-0.1)=0.905`, which means that after 10 days about 10% of the sick have died.

Comment: its not suppose to make sense as a real life senario

Comment: Are your constants all from the same problem, resp. correctly rescaled? The non-trivial equilibrium state is at s=0.006 and h=0.2. Also, 3 births per time unit and 10000 people seems a little low. But as you said, not realistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you would use, for instance, `scipy.integrate.odeint` and compute

```
def odesys(u,t):
    h, s = u
    return [ -.05*h*s+.0003*h, .05*h*s-.01*s]

h0, s0 = 9000, 100
t0, tf = 0, 0.10

t = linspace(t0, tf, 301)
sol = odeint(odesys, [h0, s0], t)
h, s = sol.T
plot(t,h, label="healthy")
plot(t,s, label="sick")
```

And if you have to use Euler, using the same interface if would look like

```
def odeinteuler(f, y0, tspan):
     y = zeros([len(tspan),len(y0)])
     y[0,:]=y0
     for k in range(1, len(tspan)):
          y[k,:] = y[k-1,:]+(t[k]-t[k-1])*array(f(y[k-1], t[k-1]))
     return y

sol = odeint(odesys, [h0, s0], t)
```

Comment: what does the h0 and s0 stand for?

Comment: within this code for the line    sol=odeint(odesys, [h0,s0],t) it says that the h0 and s0 are undefined what are they supposed to be?

Comment: These are the initial values for h and s.